# This website is extremely Lynx-friendly, but how?

Tags: lynx

I was reading a few articles today, when I stumbled upon this:
https://www.pnas.org/content/111/24/8788

When you open the page in Lynx, it's very clean, without extra elements, and even with markdown symbols. When I check the HTML source, I just don't understand how they've done that. Can someone tell me how it is done?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I finally found it. There's an "alternative" meta tag in the HTML version, pointing to the plain text version of the page, and Lynx is opening that automatically.